# Creating Comma Separated Values in Batch Scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

I have written a piece of code in Batch script which is somewhat like :

```
( 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get name
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get domain 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get manufacturer 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get model 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get username 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get systemtype
) >> file.txt
```

The contents of `file.txt` are :

```
ABC123  
xyz.com  
Hewlett-Packard  
HP xw4400 Workstation  
ABC123\Administrator  
x64-based PC
```

I want above information to be stored in CSV format as follows :

```
ABC123 , xyz.com , Hewlett-Packard , HP xw4400 Workstation , ABC123\Administrator , x64-based PC
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (
    'wmic /node:localhost computersystem get name^,domain^,manufacturer^,model^,username^,systemtype /format:csv'
) do (
    for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
        echo(%%e , %%b , %%c , %%d , %%g , %%f
    )
) >> file.txt
```

In case you doub why the two `for` commands, the output of the WMIC contains an aditional carriage return character that has to be removed.

Comment: Perfect!
What if I wish to add IP address and MAC Address too?

Comment: @MandarShinde That data is available with `wmic nicconfig`. But you will need to first determine from which nic you want the data, if ip4 or ip6 or both. The way to get the data is the same that the posted code. Retrieve one set of fields and store them in variables, retrieve the second set and store in variables. Then output the variables content into the output file.

Comment: What if I have to execute another `wmic` command (say, `wmic  cpu`) and append it's output next to the output above mentioned command (`wmic computersystem`) so that they are seen in the same row?

Comment: @MandarShinde, the same as above. In the `for` commands, instead of echoing the data, save the values inside variables. When you have all the required information in variables, then `echo %var1%,%var2%,... >> file.txt`

Comment: Your script mentioned above works absolutely fine. But I, being a novice in Batch Scripting, am not able to understand certain things. First of all, meaning of `"tokens=2-7"`. When I changed it to `"tokens=1-6"`, the output changed. Second thing is, in the `echo` statement, you used `%%e , %%b , %%c , %%d , %%g , %%f`. Why not alphabetically `%%b , %%c , %%d , %%e , %%f , %%g`? (Might be a silly doubt, apologies for that.)

Comment: @MandarShinde, If you directly execute the wmic command, you will see there is a first, non required field (the node), it is omitted using the `2-7`. Also, the fields in wmic output are alphabetically sorted, so the command output and your output are not the same. This is the reason for the disorder of the variables, getting the required order.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic computersystem get name') DO SET N=%%i
FOR /F %%i IN ('wmic computersystem get domain') DO SET D=%%i
echo %N%;%D% > output.csv
```

Comment: Tried this. It is just displaying series of commas in the output file.

Comment: If you typed it at the console, you need to change %% into %. The way it is written is correct if you save it in a batch file and run it - not for typing in by hand.

Comment: No, I typed that in a batch file and executed it.

Comment: Try copying it and pasting it, rather than typing it.

Comment: Same results. Only commas are being displayed.